# ARCore and Sceneform – Add normal map to canonical face mesh texture

Tags: android, augmented-reality, arcore, sceneform

I am working on an AR application using ARCore Sceneform. I was trying to add normal map to a face mesh texture. But there is no documentation or demo available on that.

```
Texture.builder()
   .setSource(this, R.drawable.cartoon)
   .setUsage(Texture.Usage.COLOR)
   .build()
   .thenAccept(texture -> faceMeshTexture = texture);
```

addOnUpdateListener:

```
for (AugmentedFace face: faceList) {

    if (!faceNodeMap.containsKey(face)) {

        AugmentedFaceNode faceNode = new AugmentedFaceNode(face);
        faceNode.setParent(scene);
        // faceNode.setFaceRegionsRenderable(faceRegionsRenderable);
        faceNode.setFaceMeshTexture(faceMeshTexture);
        faceNodeMap.put(face, faceNode);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this article](https://medium.com/temy/dynamic-textures-in-sceneform-98d7a2d35406) about using custom materials in ARCore. 
I do not know your case, but you might need to create a custom material as described in the article and for that you need a dummy object.

Comment: I read that doc and I understand the stuff in that. But I am not adding any 3d object in that. I am working on Mesh3D and applying Texture on face. How I can add material to that texture.

Answer (score 0):

Sceneform framework provides you with a default material definitions that allow developers to get plausibly looking materials. So, you can add a **`normal map`** for your canonical face mesh using `JSON`ish code in **`.sfa`** or **`.mat`** file.

Look at this **[example](https://github.com/google-ar/sceneform-android-sdk/tree/master/samples/solarsystem/app/sampledata/models)** at GitHub.

Here's code snippet:

```
{
  materials: [
    {
      name: 'Planet_Mat',
      parameters: [
        { baseColorFactor: [ 1, 1, 1, 1, ], },
        { baseColor: 'Planet_Mat_baseColor', },
        { normal: 'Planet_Mat_normal', },
        { metallicFactor: 1, },
        { metallicRoughness: 'Planet_Mat_occlusionRoughnessMetallic', },
        { emissiveFactor: [ 0, 0, 0, 1, ], },
      ],
      source: 'build/sceneform_sdk/default_materials/gltf_material.sfm',
    },
  ],
  model: {
    attributes: [
      'Position',
      'TexCoord',
      'Orientation',
    ],
    collision: {},
    file: 'sampledata/models/Planet/Planet.gltf',
    name: 'Planet',
    recenter: true,
    scale: 0.5,
  },
  samplers: [
    {
      file: 'sampledata/models/Planet/Planet_Mat_baseColor.png',
      name: 'Planet_Mat_baseColor',
      pipeline_name: 'Planet_Mat_baseColor.png',
    },
    {
      file: 'sampledata/models/Planet/Planet_Mat_normal.png',
      name: 'Planet_Mat_normal',
      params: {
        usage_type: 'Normal',
      },
      pipeline_name: 'Planet_Mat_normal.png',
    },
  ],
}
```

Comment: I understand that but how I will attach the material to the mesh. Because ARCore generate a mesh on runtime. I am not using a ModelRenderable. I am using Texture alone.

Comment: In your case there's no way to do it. Normal map must be connected with the UV vertices of the model.

Comment: There is a method called setFaceMeshMaterialOverride() in the AugmentedFaceNode class which takes Material as a parameter and update it to the face mesh. I think the problem is with my material.

Comment: The main question is whether this method works with normal maps or not?

Comment: I try with MaterialFactory.makeTransparentWithTexture() and it worked. Now I am trying by creating a custom material. I hope it will work.

Comment: @DheerajRijhwani, congrats!